# can I delete old vmlinuz in /boot manually?

Tags: kernel

My /boot is full. apt-get autoremove autoclean not working.
I chose to delete old linux-image* manually. There are many files like: config*VERSION, vmlinuz*VERSION, initrd.img*VERSION...

can these be deleted manually too?

VERSION is old version (some of them are dated 2012!).

Comment: You *can* delete these files by hand, but many of them will be regenerated during system updates unless the packages that create the files are removed.  Prior to removing these files, you should be sure that you know what version of Ubuntu you are running so that you do not accidentally remove the image of the running OS.  `uname -r` will provide you with the currently executing version.

Answer (score 11):

It's *possible* to delete just about any file manually, including kernels and initial RAM disks (initrds); however, when the file was installed by a package (as these were), deleting them manually leaves the package system in an inconsistent state. Thus, deleting the files manually is not recommended. I have three suggestions for how to proceed.

---

### Approach 1:

My first choice is this:

1. Type `uname -r` to discover what kernel you're currently running. For instance, one of my systems returns `4.8.0-51-generic`.
2. Type `ls /boot/vml*` to see all your installed kernels.
3. Select a kernel from those listed that is *not* the one you're currently using, and that's not the oldest one (which is probably the "base" of the kernel series). The kernel that comes just "before" the one you're running is a good candidate. That might be `vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic`, for example.
4. Type `dpkg -S /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.0-46-generic`, changing the kernel version as necessary. (Note that's an uppercase `-S` in the command.) This should reveal the package name associated with that kernel. In this example, it's `linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic`. Note that you should *not* pass a kernel with a name that ends in `.efi.signed` to `dpkg -S`; these kernels are installed in a different way that won't work with this command.
5. Type `sudo dpkg -P linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic` (changing the kernel version number, of course). This tells the system to delete the package. This may is likely to result in a complaint about broken dependencies. In this case, you should add the package(s) it claims as being dependent on the one you said to remove. In my case, I had to make the command `sudo dpkg -P linux-image-4.8.0-46-generic linux-signed-image-4.8.0-46-generic linux-image-extra-4.8.0-46-generic` (deleting three packages rather than one).
6. With any luck, the preceding command will work and clear up enough space for `sudo apt-get autoremove` to work.

---

### Approach 2:

If this *doesn't* work, then I recommend manually deleting the `.efi.signed` version of a kernel you're *not* using, if it's present. These files are not installed directly; they're created by merging the standard kernel image with a small signature file installed from another package. Thus, deleting them won't upset the package system in the same way that manually deleting a non-signed kernel file will. Note, however, that if Secure Boot is active on your computer, or even if it's not but GRUB is configured to boot through the `.efi.signed` version of the kernel, deleting this file will make it impossible to boot that kernel. Thus, it's important that you not delete the `.efi.signed` version of a kernel you're currently using.

---

### Approach 3:

Another approach is to *temporarily* move your `/boot` directory off of its separate partition and onto the regular root (`/`) filesystem. Note that although I've done similar things for other reasons, I've not tried this exact procedure for your exact reason; but it *should* work. Note also that this is rather risky; a mistake at the wrong point could render your system unbootable! If you're willing to take the chance, the procedure is:

1. Type `sudo mkdir /boot2` to create the `/boot2` directory that will temporarily house your kernels.
2. Type `sudo umount /boot/efi`. This command will fail on BIOS-based computers, but is necessary if your computer boots via EFI.
3. Type `sudo cp -a /boot/* /boot2/` to copy everything from `/boot` to `/boot2`.
4. Type `sudo umount /boot` to unmount the `/boot` directory.
5. Type `sudo rm -rf /boot`. This deletes the old `/boot` mount point and any files that may have wound up accidentally placed "under" it.
6. Type `sudo mv /boot2 /boot`. This renames your copy to the original location, as far as Linux is concerned.
7. Proceed with your `sudo apt-get autoremove` operation. This should succeed.
8. Type `sudo mv /boot /boot2` to move the updated copy of your kernels out of the way.
9. Type `sudo mkdir /boot` to create a fresh mount point for your `/boot` partition.
10. Type `sudo mount /boot` to restore the original `/boot` partition. Note that it will still be too full.
11. Type `sudo rm -rf /boot/*` to delete the contents of the original `/boot` partition.
12. Type `sudo cp -a /boot2/* /boot/` to copy your modified `/boot` directory to the `/boot` partition.
13. Reboot to be sure everything works.
14. Type `sudo rm -rf /boot2` to delete the temporary files.

A mistake (either by me or by you) could create serious problems, including a complete inability to boot the system. Thus, this approach is something of a last-resort one.

---

### Moving Forward

It's imperative that you do a periodic `sudo apt-get autoremove` to keep the `/boot` partition from overfilling. Personally, I do this almost every time I upgrade my packages, and especially if I notice a new kernel was installed. Note that there are a couple of official bugs related to this issue:

- [Kernels not autoremoving, causing out of space error on LVM or Encrypted installation or on any installation, when /boot partition gets full](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1357093)
- [Size of /boot partition is too small](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1465050)

The first of those bugs can be fixed for existing systems, but for various reasons even the official released fix isn't 100% effective. The second bug is about a choice made at system installation time, so existing systems continue to suffer from a too-small `/boot` partition moving forward. The only way to fix that issue is to resize your partitions to increase the size of `/boot`. Personally, I consider 500 MiB a *minimum* reasonable size for `/boot` these days.

Comment: Approach #3 looks scary. I'll have to read it 2 or 3 more times to see if I can follow the logic. But in step #3 and #12, shouldn't the cp be recursive? I may have other issues, but that's a start.

Comment: A tweak on approach 2 would be to zero out (not remove)  all the files in /boot associated with an old kernel.  That keeps the package manager happy, and may give it enough room to work and actually purge/remove the unwanted files using approach 1.

Comment: @heynnema, the `-a` option to `cp` causes a recursive copy, but unlike `-r`, preserves ownership and permissions. @ubfan1, that's an interesting idea, and it would probably work.